# Copy a variably named worksheet from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently using code that I found a few years ago to copy one worksheet to a new workbook, but it uses cells.copy which removes some important formatting. I'd like to use sheets.copy instead but the sheet names are constantly changing and I'm not sure how to code that. Thanks for your help. Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
Sub SheetsToFiles()
 'Takes a sheet from a workbook and turns it into a file named after the 
 sheet name


Dim mySourceWB As Workbook
Dim mySourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim myDestWB As Workbook
Dim myNewFileName As String

'   First capture current workbook and worksheet
Set mySourceWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set mySourceSheet = ActiveSheet


'   Build new file name based
myNewFileName = mySourceWB.Path & "\" & mySourceSheet.Name & ".xlsx"


'   Add new workbook and save with name of sheet from other file
Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=myNewFileName
Set myDestWB = ActiveWorkbook

'   Copy over sheet from previous file
mySourceWB.Activate
Cells.Copy
myDestWB.Activate
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False


'   Resave new workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Save

'   Close active workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Close


End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any pattern to the sheet names?

Comment: No. They're project titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `Worksheet.copy` method to copy the Worksheet to the new Workbook, this should preserve the formatting of the original sheet. Here's the code updated with comments:

```
Sub SheetsToFiles()
 'Takes a sheet from a workbook and turns it into a file named after the Sheet Name

Dim mySourceWB As Workbook
Dim mySourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim myDestWB As Workbook
Dim myNewFileName As String

'   First capture current workbook and worksheet
Set mySourceWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set mySourceSheet = ActiveSheet

'   Build new file name based
myNewFileName = mySourceWB.Path & "\" & mySourceSheet.Name & ".xlsx"

'   Create a new Workbook with one blank Worksheet (this will be deleted later)
Set myDestWB = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

'   Copy sheet to DestWB and paste after the first Worksheet
mySourceSheet.Copy After:=myDestWB.Worksheets(1)

'   Delete the unused Worksheet, turn off alerts to bypass the confirmation box
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
myDestWB.Worksheets(1).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'   Save with name of sheet from other file
myDestWB.SaveAs Filename:=myNewFileName

'   Close Destination workbook
myDestWB.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: No probs. Just noticed this is your first Stack Overflow question (congrats! :D). If the answer is useful can you please mark the answer as correct by clicking the tick-box next to the post? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ,

```
Sub SheetsToFiles()
'Takes a sheet from a workbook and turns it into a file named after the

    Dim mySourceWB As Workbook
    Dim mySourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim myDestWB As Workbook
    Dim myNewFileName As String

    '   First capture current workbook and worksheet
    Set mySourceWB = ActiveWorkbook
    Set mySourceSheet = ActiveSheet


    '   Build new file name based
    myNewFileName = mySourceWB.Path & "\" & mySourceSheet.Name & ".xlsx"

    '   Add new workbook and save with name of sheet from other file
    Workbooks.Add
    Set myDestWB = ActiveWorkbook
    myDestWB.SaveAs Filename:=myNewFileName

    '   Copy over sheet from previous file
    mySourceSheet.Range("A1:Z100").Copy Destination:=myDestWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z100")

    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    '   Resave new workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    '   Close active workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Adjust the range inside the code, it should paste the whole range as it.

Comment: There are groupings that are being ungrouped and all column widths are reset even when I change the range. Also the range will change with each worksheet as not all reports are the same.